# Using standard Fit fixtures AND FitLibrary DoFixture seamlessly in one test

Tags: java, fitnesse, fit-framework

Studying the standard Fit fixtures types I came along the DoFixture which is provided by FitLibrary - because I need the flexible approach this fixture type offers, I downloaded the latest version (20110222) of FitLibrary and set up my environment exactly as stated in the readme.

```
!path fitlibrary.jar
!path fitnesse.jar
!path lib/*.jar
!define TEST_RUNNER {fitlibrary.suite.FitLibraryServer}
```

The consequence of this is that apparently all my tests run in something that I think they call "flow" mode, or is it their "business rules mode"?? I simply don't know.

All I know is that none of my tests work anymore. For example: I got a RowEntryFixture named `ServerDeclaration` and having a test table for this fixture now results in:

```
Missing class or Missing method. Possibly:

* public Type getServerDeclaration() { }
* public Type serverDeclaration() { }
```

My question is: how do I MIX Fit table styles along with FitLibrary table styles in one test? It must be possible, as FitLibrary test table styles are often called an unofficial "add-on" to Fit!

Does anybody know how this can be achieved??
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the first table, with |server declaration| is not being treated correctly as the name of a class by FitLibrary. A quick fix is to write the class name out in full: |mypackage.ServerDeclaration. I will change FitLibrary to handle this case.

Nothing special needs to be done to combine Fit and FitLibrary tables, as long as FitLibraryServer is the TEST_RUNNER, as you've defined it above. FitLibrary automatically runs Fit tables when it finds them.

Cheers, Rick

Comment: thanks! I just tried it and it works! I am so used to Fit that naturally I never wrote class names of fixtures in full... ;-) I used FitLibrary fixtures a few years ago and back then I did not need to change the runner - what exactly is that for??

Comment: FitLibrary now has a different runtime architecture from Fit, so needs to start up differently. It has a scope model, which allows several fixtures/objects to be current at once, including global ones that provide general actions and special actions like '''is'''. It's on my list of things to write up...